# Abstracting an ArrayList<E> iteration to build a reusable method

Tags: java, design-patterns, arraylist, iterator, abstract

At the moment i have this code working but repetitive:

```
Iterator<Moo> it6 = moos.iterator();
   while (it6.hasNext()) {
      Moo m = it6.next();
      m.update();
      if (!m.isActive())
         it6.remove();
}

Iterator<Pip> it7 = pips.iterator();
   while (it7.hasNext()) {
      Pip s = it7.next();
      s.update();
      if (!s.isActive())
         it7.remove();
}

... and other ...
```

Where pips and moos are defined on that class:

```
public class GameEngine {
   private ArrayList<Moo> moos;
   private ArrayList<Pip> pips;
   ...
```

And Class Moo/Pip like:

```
public class Moo extends GameSprite {
   ...

public class Pip extends GameSprite {
   ...
```

Can I use some design pattern(or some different implementations) to reduce the written codes and make it more elegant?

Comment: Are `isActive()` and `update()` declared in `GameSprite`?

Comment: You need to add some more information. Just adding the declaration of class doesn't help much. Where is `isActive()` defined. Where do you have those code? And what exactly those codes are doing, apart from removing the element from the `ArrayList`?

Comment: What @MarkPeters says. If yes and if you are ready to use an external library, Guava has `Iterables.removeIf()`.

Comment: isActive() is declared on GameSprite, update is an abstract method declared on GameSprite but implemented on Pip and Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `isActive()` and `update()` in `GameSprite`, you can use a generic method:

```
private static void update(List<? extends GameSprite> sprites) {

    Iterator<? extends GameSprite> it = sprites.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      GameSprite s = it.next();
      s.update();
      if (!s.isActive())
         it.remove();
    }
}
```

Then just call it with

```
update(pips);
update(moos);
```

Comment: Seems everybody posts the same answer simultaneously. +1 because you were first.

Comment: @Axel if this was the case, then at least you could upvote others answers for the sake of modesty!

Answer (score 1):

make sure GameSprite class has isActive() and update() as methods (abstract if the implementation is not the same)

```
   public void removeInactive(ArrayList<? extends GameSprite> itList){
        Iterator<GameSprite> it = itList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            GameSprite s = it.next();
            s.update();
            if (!s.isActive())
                it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a common interface that provides the `update()` and `isActive() methods.  Either pull them up to the`GameSprite`class, or add another interface (e.g.,`Updatable`) that all your classes implement.

Once you've done that, you can extract this common code to a method:

```
public updateAll (Iterable<? extends GameSprite> sprites) {
   Iterator<? extends GameSprite> it = sprites.iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
      GameSprite s = it.next();
      s.update();
      if (!s.isActive())
         it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface `Updatable`:

```
public interface Updatable {
    void update();
    boolean isActive();
}
```

and have  `Moo` and `Pip` implement that interface. Then your universal Method looks like this:

```
public void update(List<? extends Updatable> items) {
    Iterator<? extends Updatable> it6 = items.iterator();
    while (it6.hasNext()) {
        Updatable m = it6.next();
        m.update();
        if (!m.isActive())
            it6.remove();
    }
}
```